# How to get desired height of ListBox so it doesn't have scrollbar and its content fits there

Tags: wpf

I have a `ListBox` inside a `DockPanel`. I want to find out what should be the size of the `ListBox` so it doesn't have the scroll bar. I use `ListBox.DesiredSize` but actually `DesiredSize` is equal to `ListBox.ActualWidth` / `Height` and the `ListBox` has scrollbar because there are more items that can fit its height.
How to get real desired size ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get rid of scrollbar in Listbox instead of creating static height in wpf application, you can disable scrollbar property.

**In XAML:**

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
<ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
```

**In C#:**

```
myListBox.SetValue(ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibilityProperty, ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled);
myListBox.SetValue(ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibilityProperty, ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled);
```

You can disable the scrollbar

***Or else***

```
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
```

and set any height for Listbox scroll bar will be visible only content reaches its max Listbox height.

**Or**

Try this to achieve the desired height by binding the ListBox height property to the ActualHeight of the LayoutRoot Grid via the XAML below:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="LightGray">
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width=".24*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width=".73*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height=".9*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height=".1*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<ListBox Name="Subdivisions" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSubdivisionViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Subdivisions}" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" Height="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=ActualHeight}" >
```

The important bit being:

```
 Height="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot, Path=ActualHeight}"
```

Also achievable via ancestor type:

```
 Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}"
```

> Its my working code you can change it from grid to Dockpanel.

Comment: Thank you but I want to resize ListBox so scrollbar isn't needed - so it fits all items. I clarified my question.

Comment: @Bohus I have updated my answer. Hope it helps for you.

Answer (score 1):

> How to get real desired size ?

The desired size of the `ListBox` is calculated automatically if you don't explicitly set its `Height` or `VerticalAlignment` property and avoid putting it in a `Panel` that measures its children with an infinite space such as a `StackPanel`.

The desired size of the `ListBox` itself is however not the same as the aggregated size of all `ListBoxItem` containers. In fact, there is no easy way to calculate this height exactly since not all containers are generated up front provided that you haven't disabled the UI virtualization of the `ListBox`.

The easiest workaround/solution would probably be to get the height of the first container once the `ListBox` has been loaded and then multiply this value with the actual number of items, e.g.:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lb" Loaded="lb_Loaded">
    <ListBoxItem>1</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>2</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>3</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

---

```
private void lb_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxItem lbi = lb.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as ListBoxItem;
    if (lbi != null)
    {
        lb.Height = lbi.ActualHeight * lb.Items.Count + /* add some offset */ 5;
    }
}
```